# What are the limitatios of angular displacement for the period of oscillation formula $T=2π\sqrt{\ell/g}$ for simple pendulums?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, oscillators, approximations

I'm currently working on my physics school investigation, where I try to determine the limitations of the formula for period od oscillation for simple pendulum. I didn't know that this investigation would be so hard to explain, so I'm asking your help.

I have measured the period of oscillation for 3 pendulums, 60, 40 and 20 long. (see teble below). Then, using Desmos graphing calculator I determined the trend line for these points. It happent that it is a quadratic function. My hypothesis states that for small angles, as the period of oscillation formuls states, the period has to remain constant, because this formula a "small angle" approximation formula.

(Table of measurements for 60cm pendulum)(column 1 - angular displacement, column 2-number of trials, column 3-time measured, column 4-number of complete oscillations, column 5-period, column 6-average period)

```
    10  1   60.05   39  1.540   1.543
        2   60.46   39  1.550   
        3   60.17   39  1.543   
        4   60.24   39  1.545   
        5   59.94   39  1.537   
    15  1   60.14   39  1.542   1.542
        2   61.66   40  1.542   
        3   61.76   40  1.544   
        4   60.08   39  1.541   
    20  1   60.42   39  1.549   1.544
        2   61.65   40  1.541   
        3   61.77   40  1.544   
        4   61.81   40  1.545   
        5   61.70   40  1.543   
    25  1   60.39   39  1.548   1.548
        2   60.27   39  1.545   
        3   60.39   39  1.548   
        4   60.46   39  1.550   
    30  1   60.61   39  1.554   1.555
        2   60.71   39  1.557   
        3   60.79   39  1.559   
        4   60.50   39  1.551   
        5   60.70   39  1.556   
    35  1   61.29   39  1.572   1.568
        2   61.14   39  1.568   
        3   61.34   39  1.573   
        4   61.07   39  1.566   
        5   60.98   39  1.564   
    40  1   61.47   39  1.576   1.578
        2   61.63   39  1.580   
        3   58.40   37  1.578   
    45  1   60.33   38  1.588   1.590
        2   60.46   38  1.591   
        3   60.44   38  1.591   
    50  1   60.80   38  1.600   1.598
        2   60.60   38  1.595   
        3   60.71   38  1.598   
        4   60.78   38  1.599   
    55  1   61.12   38  1.608   1.609
        2   61.14   38  1.609   
        3   61.21   38  1.611   
    60  1   60.25   37  1.628   1.629
        2   60.37   37  1.632   
        3   60.27   37  1.629   
        4   60.23   37  1.628   
    65  1   60.76   37  1.642   1.643
        2   60.86   37  1.645   
        3   60.82   37  1.644   
        4   60.69   37  1.640   
    70  1   61.23   37  1.655   1.656
        2   61.26   37  1.656   
        3   59.81   36  1.661   
        4   61.16   37  1.653   
        5   61.23   37  1.655
```

[image]

When i asked my teacher a suggestion on how can i justify the limitation of the graph, he suggested me to find the percentage change of period for each degree (according to the trend line) and set a boundary. For instance there the percentage change of period will not exceed 1%.

[image: percentage change of period values for 60cm pendulum]

Table shows the percentage change of period values for 60cm pendulum.

My question is, what would be a reasonable percentage change boundary that i should set, to show the limitation of the formula and how do justify this choice?

All the data was collected without and technology, so the data points may have errors in it. For this experiment my teacher helped me to build the pendulum stand, where at the origin of the pendulum, there is a transporter ruler to measure the angle, and time was recorded using phone timer app.

Also, I would like to know how could i possibly find the reaction error in my data using this data collection technique?

Comment: [Relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mechanics)#Power_series_solution_for_the_elliptic_integral).

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable boundary depends on why a person will use the pendulum as a timer.  If need requires accuracy of 2%, then 2% is a reasonable boundary.  But 1% to 1.5% would be a more "safe" boundary.  This allows for effects of equipment and environment that cannot be controlled.  As for reaction error, repeat the experiment with the same initial conditions.  Start at the same angle many times and look at the distribution of data.  The standard deviation is often considered a reasonable calculation of measurement uncertainty.